# How do I parse a string with a comma-separated list of quoted substrings in bash?

Tags: bash

I would like to read in an unlimited amount of args instead of only reading in a set of 3.

Take the below file:

`packages`:

```
deb "bat" [args: "https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/releases/download/v0.4.1/bat_0.4.1_amd64.deb", "$HOME", "bat_0.4.1_amd64.deb"]
```

`custom function`:

```
apt_install_from_file() {

    declare -r FILE_PATH="$1" # packages
    regex["deb"]='deb "(.*)" \[args: "(.*)", "(.*)", "(.*)"\]'

    if [ -e "$FILE_PATH" ]; then
       cat < "$FILE_PATH" | while read -r LINE; do
          if [[ $LINE =~ ${regex[deb]} ]]; then
              # ...
         fi
       done
   fi
}
```

Comment: Do you know what the actual format is? If it's YAML, better to invoke an actual YAML parser rather than write a regex -- if you convert the YAML to JSON, then you can work with the JSON using tools like `jq`.

Comment: @charlesDuffy If you are talking about the file `packages` then it is just a plain-text file

Comment: BTW, the `cat` is not just utterly unnecessary but actively harmful -- it puts your `while read` loop in a subshell so it can't change variables that are seen by the rest of the script.

Comment: `[args: "foo", "bar", "baz"]` isn't plain text -- it's a structured data format that something is expected to parse. The question is *which* parser is used for it. If the answer is that it's a one-off bespoke built-to-purpose parser... well, it's still a parser.

Comment: @charlesDuffy, correct, it is a data structure that I created, however, I would like the parser to be able to handle when `[args: "foo", "bar", "baz" ... ]` contains more than just 3 arguments. I am unsure as to changing my current structure to handle this new condition.

Comment: To be clear, my advice is *not* to use bespoke serialization formats -- using JSON and then being able to invoke `jq` is a lot less heartache, means you get parsing/generation tools for a wide array of languages "for free", and will mean you've got coverage for the corner cases (with this format, what happens if you want to put a literal quote character inside an argument?)

Comment: BTW, the use of lowercase variable names in my answer is deliberate -- see POSIX spec @ http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html: *The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities* -- to be read keeping in mind that setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, so the namespace is necessarily shared.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: How about an approach that just involves reading the args list inside `[..]` in a variable (regex match) and later splitting them on `,` and cleaning up the spaces (leading and trailing)

Comment: If you split them on `,`s, then you can't have commas inside your quoted strings; you're constraining the data format by taking that approach.

Comment: @NicholasAdamou: Do you expect to have `,` between any of your quoted strings? just to clarify!

Comment: @Inian yes, I do expect to have `,` between my quoted strings.

Comment: @Inian, ...are you asking about *between* or *inside*? And I'd argue that the decision should be deliberate to *constrain* string contents -- assuming that a string can contain anything but a `"` as its contents -- rather than coming from a perspective of assuming that nothing is legal and only allowing a minimal set of whitelisted contents.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Fair point, sure! my approach wouldn't work then. I need to be able to build a proper CSV parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Insofar as this is your own homebuilt serialization format, **don't do that.** It's much more robust to use off-the-shelf formats and tools: With JSON, for example, you could use `jq`, `jsawk`, the JSON modules in Perl/Python, etc.

But to answer the question as asked...

---

Put a match group around your potentially-repeated items, and then pick smaller items out of that group until no more are available -- like so:

```
apt_install_from_file() {
  local line multi_args_str last_arg
  local -a args
  local deb_re='deb[[:space:]]+"([^"]*)"[[:space:]]+\[args:[[:space:]]+(("([^"]*)",[[:space:]]*)*)("([^"]*)")[[:space:]]*\]'
  local multi_args_re='[[:space:]]*"([^"]*)",[[:space:]]*'

  args=( )
  while read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ $deb_re ]] || continue
    [[ $- = *x* ]] && declare -p BASH_REMATCH >&2 # debug
    multi_args_str=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    last_arg=${BASH_REMATCH[6]}
    args=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )
    while [[ $multi_args_str =~ $multi_args_re ]]; do
      args+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )
      multi_args_str=${multi_args_str#"${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"}
    done
    args+=( "$last_arg" )
    printf 'Parsed line %s to array:\n' "$line"
    declare -p args
  done
}
```

...properly emits, when given your line of input:

```
Parsed line deb "bat" [args: "https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/releases/download/v0.4.1/bat_0.4.1_amd64.deb", "/home/6lEee0", "bat_0.4.1_amd64.deb"] to array:
declare -a args=([0]="bat" [1]="/home/6lEee0" [2]="bat_0.4.1_amd64.deb")
```

Similarly, given a longer input line, it can return:

```
Parsed line deb "bat" [args: "https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/releases/download/v0.4.1/bat_0.4.1_amd64.deb", "/home/pShbET", "bat_0.4.1_amd64.deb", "foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"] to array:
declare -a args=([0]="bat" [1]="https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/releases/download/v0.4.1/bat_0.4.1_amd64.deb" [2]="/home/pShbET" [3]="bat_0.4.1_amd64.deb" [4]="foo" [5]="bar" [6]="baz" [7]="\"qux\"")
```

See this in action at https://ideone.com/fC37Fq